# Duplicidade de registros entre duas tabelas

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas que possuem campo telefone. Precisava fazer uma consulta onde buscasse todos os telefones iguais entre essas duas tabelas. É possível?

Comment: Sim, só fazer um join entre elas onde os valores nessas colunas são iguais. Quer tentar?

Comment: Apresenta suas tabelas e a consulta que está tentando para podemos ajuda-lo melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça um join entre as duas tabelas, igual o exemplo abaixo:

```
Select *
from tabela1 
     inner join tabela2 on tabela1.telefone = tabela2.telefone
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer algo parecido com isso

```
    SELECT t1.NumeroTelefone FROM tabelaTelefone1 t1
    INNER JOIN tabelaTelefone2 t2
       ON t1.NumeroTelefone = t2.NumeroTelefone
```